# initialize an array of unique_ptrs

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, unique-ptr

I'm trying to build an entity-component class which stores components in a vector of std::arrays of std::unique_ptrs of derived Component pointers, like so:

```
vector<pair<int, array<unique_ptr<Component>, 32>>> components;
```

When trying to create a new array for a new component, though, even using move(), I wind up getting the following error:

```
this->count++;
vector<pair<int, array<unique_ptr<Component>, 32>>> component_set;
this->components.emplace_back(make_pair(this->count, move(component_set)));

    Error   1   error C2248: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr' : 
    cannot access private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>'   
    c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\array  211 1   
    entity
```

is this a problem with using the std::array class, or am I just doing this entirely wrong (which is possible?)

Comment: You appear to be trying to use `std::array` as an allocator for a `std::vector<int>`...

Comment: Is the first code example supposed to have `unique_ptr` instead of `shared_ptr`?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Updated. It's supposed to be a vector of pairs of int,array.

Comment: As @wakjah said, this is a vector of ```int```s, whose allocator is an array of unique pointers. I don't think that's right.

Comment: Your code sample is very strange. I assume `components` is the vector of pairs. And you're initializing another vector of pairs (`component_set`), and then making another pair from that, and then trying to add this pair of int and vectors of pairs of int and array of `unique_ptr` to the original vector? I think [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e34ef5f5667ef04) is what you're looking for. Or [another option](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54811c6928e5e035)

Comment: that is basically what I'm going for, Praetorian, sorry it's strange. Unfortunately, neither of your posted options seem to work, but the first one does give me a different error

    Error 1 error C2664: 
    'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::pair(const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &) throw()' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' to 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &' c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xmemory0 617 1 entity

which tells me that might be on the right track at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the use of `emplace_back()` jumps through a `std::pair<...>` where it really shouldn't. Try

```
this->componets.emplace_back(int, std::array<std::unique_ptr<Component>, 32>());
```

You actually try add something into `component` which seems to be of a type would *contain* an entity of the type of `components`.

Comment: I'm using a bitset to represent entities, and I want to use arrays to represent sets of components, where the index of the array corresponds to the derived type of that component. So if COMPONENT_POSITION = 2 then the instance of Component: Position() will be at components[id][COMPONENT_POSITION]

Comment: @KennethRapp: did you read my response and try the suggestion? I don't really mind what you are using this construct for! However, you tried to insert a `std::pair<int, std::vector<std::pair<int, std::array<std::unique_ptr<Component>, 32>>>>` (the result of `std::make_pair(int, component_set)`) into a `std::vector<pair<int, std::array<std::unique_ptr<Component>, 32>>>`: that's not going to work.

Comment: I did try your suggestion, and got an error that the type name was not allowed. However, I am still working on it. Thank you.